# Do WiX patches update registry settings?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3, wix3.5

This is a two-part question:

1. Do "just-WiX" WiX patches update components with RegistryValue key-paths when those RegistryValues are different in the updated build?
2. Do "admin-image" WiX patches perform differently or the same in regards to such components?

Comment: I suppose quick test can give you the answers faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches should update registry settings.